# how to check function having parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.isFunction(sdopen) && sdopen()
```

is working fine

but how to check function if there is a parameter like

```
sdopen(uu)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property

> The length property specifies the number of arguments expected by the function.

```
$.isFunction(sdopen) && sdopen.length == 1 && sdopen(uu)
```

As  [Praveen Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462627/praveen-kumar), correctly pointed out. For checking whether it is a function there is no need to use jQuery, it can be achieved using pure JavaScript.

```
typeof sdopen == "function"
```

```js
function sdopen(a) {
  alert(a)
}

$.isFunction(sdopen) && sdopen.length == 1 && sdopen('Yahooooooooooo');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I guess using `typeof sdopen == "function"` is better than using `$.isFunction(sdopen)` and we can totally eradicate the use of jQuery.

Comment: @Quentin I guess we are always rivals on this topic. :P

Comment: I wonder ! why u want to eradicate use of jquery?

Comment: @user5419119, If you are using jQuery for other purpose then its fine. However only to load jquery to test whether its function is not required.

Comment: yes, I am using jquery for other purposes in the project also .I think jquery is the reason many people are able to use javascript so easily.